# Input shrinks when user starts typing

Tags: html, css, forms, css-grid

The contactfields on my [website](https://christoph-fricke.de) are shrinking as soon as the user starts typing on a mobile device. I could not detect this behavior in a desktop browser window at any size.

The contactfield is structured with the relativly new `css grid`.

How to recreate the bug:

1. Open my [website](https://christoph-fricke.de) on your mobile device
2. Scroll down to the input field
3. Focus one and start typing

---

I already tried to fix it trough applying a `width` and `min-width` to the inputs but this did not fixed it.

I gathered information in a spreadsheet about different browsers and devices to find out wether the bug appears or not.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D3_7zh8u2MFAx5vt_mKCA9bjEI9crdDwwOSlucLLwfM/edit?usp=sharing

I think that it might be a browser bug since `css grid` is relatively new?! Are you able to recreate the bug? Do you have any ideas how to fix it other than removing the `css grid` and structuring it with `flexbox`?

I would like to try to get the browser companies notified if it appears to be a browser bug so they can fix it...

```css
/*I actually use SCSS so this code will not run */
/* The grid */
.grid__form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-areas: "name email" "textarea textarea" "feedback submit";
  grid-gap: 10px;
  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-areas: "feedback" "name" "email" "textarea" "submit";
}

/* The contact form */
.contact {
  grid-area: contact;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  &__header {
    font-size: 500;
    color: $text-dark-primary;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
      @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    &--link {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: rgba($color-secondary-400, 0.87);
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: $transition-standard;
      @media screen and (max-width: 359px) {
        font-size: 1.3rem;
      }
      &:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    }
  }
  &__input {
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 2px solid rgba(black, 0.20);
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    color: $text-dark-primary;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: text;
    outline: none;
    transition: $transition-standard;
    &--name {
      grid-area: name;
    }
    &--email {
      grid-area: email;
    }
    &--textarea {
      grid-area: textarea;
      resize: none;
      min-height: 250px;
    }
    &:focus {
      border: 2px solid $color-secondary-200;
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 100%;
    }
  }
  &__submit {
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    grid-area: submit;
    justify-self: end;
  }
  &__feedback {
    grid-area: feedback;
    align-self: center;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="contact__form grid__form" action="_assets/php/sendMail.php" method="POST" novalidate>
  <input id="name" class="contact__input contact__input--name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
  <input id="email" class="contact__input contact__input--email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
  <textarea id="message" class="contact__input contact__input--textarea" type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  <p class="contact__feedback"></p>
  <button class="contact__submit button--raised" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Site is working fine.

Comment: I see the problem on my mobile device. If you completely remove the  class `.contact__input`, does the problem still occur?

Comment: @Michael_B The problem still appears... I removed `.contact__input` and after that also the modifiers `...--name` etc. Bug still exists.

Comment: @Nimish Am I allowed to ask what browser and OS you used? :)

Comment: @Michael_B It worked!!! Looks like the bug disappeared. Thank you very much! I was wrapping my head around this for a long time now.

Comment: A similar issue happens on MacOS Sierra with Chrome 61 https://github.com/rachelandrew/cssgrid-ama/issues/107?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be caused by `input` elements as grid items. Some browsers may be quirky with form elements in a grid container, being that this technology is so new.

Instead, wrap each `input` in a div. These divs now become the grid items and the inputs become their children (and are now outside the scope of grid layout).

Give each `input` a `width: 100%`, if necessary.

Comment: I was also seeing the same issue the OP was talking about in Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 on desktop.  This fixed the issue.