# Input field gets small when typing only at Chrome on Mac (perhaps CSS-Grid issue)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-grid, html-input

I created a website on which I have input fields which turn very small when I start typing anything. But this behaviour only appears at Chrome on Mac (current Version 63). The same website on Safari or at Chrome on Windows doesn't show this and I have no clue what is going on.

Here two screenshots:
[image]
[image]

I pinpointed it down that the problem is caused by my attempt to fill out the css grid column with the input field. You can see this in the (S)CSS code where I've tried to achieve this with one of these options:

```
// All these 3 options get me to the same bug:
justify-items: stretch;

// Same with this option:
input {
  width: 100%;
}

// Or this one:
input {
  justify-self: stretch;
}
```

Here the more or less minimum version of the problem. I also created a fiddle but the bug doesn't show on fiddle with Chrome on Mac :/

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3yobjcpy/)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="showcase" class="grid">
      <!-- OTHER STUFF I ARRANGE WITH GRID -->
      <form action="#" class="grid">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
      </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

SCSS:

```
input {
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 1.4em;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

#showcase {
  grid-template-columns: auto 180px;

  form {
    background: rgba(34, 34, 30, 0.75);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 1ch;
    padding: 3em;
    justify-self: stretch;

    // All these 3 options get me to the same bug:
    justify-items: stretch;

    // Same with this option:
    input {
      width: 100%;
    }

    // Or this one:
    input {
      justify-self: stretch;
    }
  }
}
```

I hope someone has an idea and can help me.

Comment: "the bug doesn't show on fiddle with Chrome on Mac" this suggests there's some other overriding style in your page causing the effect. It's probably only applied on :focus by the sound of it, have you tried inspecting it in the developer tools? You can force focus and then see what styles are being applied by the browser.

Comment: @delinear Yes I've tried :active and :focus. They add the same CSS properties on Windows and Mac. Basically adding  "outline-offset: -2px;" and "outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;". Even if I override with "none" and 0 the same issue occurs.

Comment: Possibly related (see the bottom section in my answer about browser variations): https://stackoverflow.com/q/47723114/3597276

Comment: Actually, this may be even more relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44932403/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really seems to be a bug in Chrome with the handling of input fields in combination of the grid system. I wrapped the input fields in divs and now it works like a charm.

Thanks to @Michael_B for pointing to the correct answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44934676/2224874